# Gluon Mobile - fxml file "Location is not set"

Tags: java, android, javafx, netbeans, gluon-mobile

I want to implement javafx app both on desktop and android. When I try load fxml file:

`FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ProjectSetup.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();`

I am getting an error:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.`

I tried putting it in Resources(Main), Resources(Desktop),Source Packages(Java).

Example

[image: [1]]

None of it worked.

Where should I put "ProjecSetup.fxml" to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate location for fxml files is `src/main/resources/yourpackage`. If the class which is calling `getResource()` is not located in the same package as the referenced fxml.file, i.e. `src/main/yourpackage`, you have to use an aboslute path: `fxmlLoader(getClass().getResource("/yourpackage/ProjectSetup.fxml")`. Pay attention to the leading slash

Comment: But when I created Gluon Single View Project lots of Resources folders where made. There is also no directory called src, but Source Packages.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, that's why the package structure looks different than yours. Try to access your fxml file by: `new FxmlLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/ProjectSetup.fxml")`